# have to keep adding folder to search index

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I have an 4 TB external HDD made by Touro, plugged into a USB3 port on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit PC. It is divided into 2 TB partitions.

Every time I search a folder on this drive, I am prompted to add it to the search index, to improve search performance.

I choose yes every time, but it never remembers my answer it seem.

How do I add this folder to the search index permanently?

Comment: Ensure the folder has *System* permission (Properties > Security tab > check whether *System* is listed under Group or user names) or add it if it doesn't. Once you've done that add the folder to the search index. If the folder was already added to the index before you edited its permissions then rebuild the index.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the drives to Search Index?

You can do it by going:
Start>Control Panel>Indexing Options>Modify>Select the Drives from tree>OK